# How to implement a count if and index or match function in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing

[image]

I am working on a template which records actions of specific companies during an auction. In Column J I have actions, and column K I have the company name. What I need help with is integrating a function to check the validity of a specific action. Essentially You cannot have an action of neg in column J without an action of bid in column J for a specific firm.

So I am trying to use conditional formula to create a check to see if for a given firm in column K is the count of neg less than the count of bids for the same firm in column J

These are the column names, the actions themselves are all in the same clump.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Also, breaking your question into paragraphs helps a lot in making it more understandable.

Comment: I did not do anything yet, also both actions have to be in the same column. coder The column names are as follows tname tcusip announced month day year event_id seq_id action firm value descriptor1 descriptor2 descriptor3 notes bid and neg are both entered in the column marked action

Answer (score 0):

How many actions do you have? If there are not many you could add a column for each action with a count.

For example, add a column called Compare_1 in column L and a column called Compare_2 in column M.

In column L create a countifs formula (I started in Row 3, if your data starts in row 2 you would change K3 to K2)

`=COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"neg")`

You can also modify the formulas to incorporate each type you need to compare in Compare_1 and then do the same in the next column for the Compare_2 data.

```
=IF(OR(J3="neg",J3="bid"),(COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"neg")),IF(OR(J3="dog",J3="puppy"),(COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"dog")),0))
```

and in column M create a countifs formula

`=COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"bid")`

Then create a validation column in column N with the formula

`=IF(L3=M3,"Valid","Not Valid")`.

Again to combine for Compare_2

```
=IF(OR(J3="neg",J3="bid"),(COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"bid")),IF(OR(J3="dog",J3="puppy"),(COUNTIFS(K:K,K3,J:J,"puppy")),0))
```

There could be an easier 1 step process from someone else, but this is what I came up with.